# Proper way to access variable with multiple threads

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

What is the proper way to declare and access a variable in a form that will be modified by other threads? It would seem like if you properly maintain only one instance of the class and pass it by reference everywhere, all threads would be accessing the same variable. What is the correct way to do this? Should I always encapsulate the variables in their own separate class?

Method 1:

```
Public Class frmMain

    Private _emailsync As New Object
    Public _lastemail As Date

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _lastemail = New Date(1970, 1, 1)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SendEmail() 'CalledFromAnotherThread
        If Now().Subtract(_lastemail).TotalHours > 3 Then
            SyncLock _emailsync
                _lastemail = Now()
            End SyncLock
            'MailMessage code here
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Method 2:

```
Public Class frmMain

    Private _emailsync As New Object
    Private _vars As Vars

    Private Sub frmMain_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        _vars = New Vars()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SendEmail() 'CalledFromAnotherThread
        If Now().Subtract(_vars._lastemail).TotalHours > 3 Then
            SyncLock _emailsync
                _vars._lastemail = Now()
            End SyncLock
            'MailMessage code here
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Class Vars
        Public _lastemail As Date

        Sub New()
            _lastemail = New Date(1970, 1, 1)
        End Sub
    End Class

End Class
```